# Unrecognized option: -ea,--enable-preview error shown in a Java standalone project, VSCode

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code

I have yet to find any documentation regarding this problem. In a standalone project, the following error shows up when I attempt to run a simple JUnit test. Even after configuring the launch.json file and adding the following argument to vmArgs, the same error shows up. The file use to run fine 2 weeks ago and I haven't touched it since. Is this because of a new VSCode update? Or?

The files work fine using Maven and the "Create Java Project" command.

Error:

```
Unrecognized option: -ea,--enable-preview
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: try to run VS Code command :`Java: Clean the Java language server workspace`

Comment: I have already attempted that.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the --enable-preview flag in the test configuration, in settings.json:

```
"java.test.config": [
    {
        "name": "java12",
        "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "vmargs": [ "--enable-preview" ],
    },
]
```

refer to https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/671#issuecomment-478040504

Comment: I have seen this before and was one of the first things I tried, if you read my post, I already said I attempted to add the arguments to vmArgs and the same error occured.

Comment: @Urmzd is there any other error messages ?i think something wasn't correctly configured in your VSCode installation.Have you tried to reinstall it along with the java extensions

Comment: I did a clean boot of my computer because of this issue. It did not solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your VS setup but once I also got the same issue in Eclipse configured for Java14, so **--enable-preview** flag was being used.

So I reconfigured it to jdk1.8 & now it works fine with no issues.

Comment: Ill try this and let you know, haven't used Java in a while